# Find next query selector match with javascript

Tags: javascript, selector

This is my code:

```
<div data-tabs>
  Some content
</div>
<div data-tabs-content>
  Some content
</div>
<div data-tabs><!-- Start here -->
  Some content
</div>
<div class="some-nested-divs">
  <div data-tabs-content><!-- Find only this -->
    Some content
    <div data-tabs-content>
      Some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Look at the **second** `data-tabs` element. From that element I want to find the **first** match of `data-tabs-content`.

- Let's say my `this` points to the **second** `data-tabs` now (by a click).
- Be aware of that there are 2 `data-tabs` and 3 `data-tabs-content`.
- It should **not** start from the **first** `data-tabs` or the **first** or **last** `data-tabs-content`.
- Match should be a single element object.
- jQuery is not an option.

Comment: `[...e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('[data-tabs-content]')].slice(1)` assumes you always want to ignore the first `data-tabs-content`

Comment: Are you trying to come up with a general way of selecting the next-occurring instance of `some element` from `some other element` that was clicked?

Comment: I'm not sure, is this what you want to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/kn87sf1q/

Comment: @blex It very much looks like it. Will try it out more tomorrow. Sleeping time...

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.querySelectorAll(), which returns an array-like object. You can then access the desired div using bracket notation. In this case, the desired div will be the second element at index 1.

```
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tabs-content]');
var tab2 = tabsContents[1];
```

You could also add an id to the div and use document.getElementById();

If you are set on getting to the element using this, you could use

```
this.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
```